# .click on li not working after appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending an li to a ul, for example:

```
$(".vocab-list").append( $('<li onclick="play_sound(\''+val['audioURL']+'\');" class="vocab-word" id="vocab_' + val['id']+ '"><img width="230px" height="230px" src="' + val['imageURL'] + '" /><div><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>' + val['word'] + '</div></li>').hide().fadeIn(600));
```

Now I am trying to do something onclick so using the following but its not working

```
$( ".vocab-word" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is generally the dynamic addition ... it wasn't there when the click event was set to monitor.

Try ...

```
$(document).on("click", ".vocab-word", function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

This will allow your code to monitor the event at the document level, regardless of what changes.

**UPDATE**:

The concept is to monitor above where the element will be added and I don't know your code so can't guarantee other elements you can attach to.  It is possible, depending on the complexity of your code to cause performance issues using the `$(document).on()` code ... try `$("body")` or lower HTML elements.

Comment: don't use document on, please read here `http://api.jquery.com/on/`  `Event performance` section

Comment: OK ... I'll give you a maybe on performance, but the concept is to monitor above where the element will be added and I don't know his code so can't guarantee other elements.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$(".vocab-list").on('click', '.vocab-word', function() { 
alert( "Handler for .click() called." ); 
);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/, [Handling Events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/) and [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)